# Why can I import a module on VS Code but not Sublime or Spyder?

Tags: python, api, module, pip

I have used `pip install nba_api` and I am able to access the data in VS Code but I can not access it on Sublime or Spyder. I know this is probably some newbie install problems but I am still quite new. I run this same code block:

```
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import scoreboard
import pandas as pd

scores = scoreboard.Scoreboard(game_date= "23-FEB-17")
scores = scores.get_data_frames()

print(scores)
```

on VS Code and Sublime and Spyder and get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nba_api.stats'; 'nba_api' is not a package` from the last 2. Thanks!

Comment: 1. are you using a virtual env ; 2. is it activated in Sublime / spyder 3. what happens if you execute it via a shell ?

Comment: 1. No ; 2. I am not sure what you mean but I have been running Python code in Sublime for some time now ; 3. Running my files in shell results in ```Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.```